# Apache Commons CLI Option Value Same as Name of Other Option

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I am in a situation where a valid argument for an option is the same as the name of another option.

Example:

```
options.addOption("a", true, "Option a");
options.addOption("b", false, "Option b");
```

Valid user input:

`foo -a -b` where "-b" is the argument for option a.

As of now my code gives me a MissingArgumentException.

Is there a way to handle this edge case?

Comment: The DefaultParser of commons-cli currently explicitly prevents this via the "!isArgument()" call in the following line:

`else if (currentOption != null && currentOption.acceptsArg() && isArgument(token))`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by handling the MissingArgumentException and processing it that way.